# Not able to remove a package completely in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, uninstallation, mosquitto

Tried removing mosquitto from Ubuntu, I probably forgot to stop the service/process. While mosquitto was removed (using apt-get remove and apt-get purge and autoremove etc), I can still access (run) mosquitto on command-prompt.

When I try to remove it again, it says

> Package 'mosquitto' is not installed, so not removed

I cannot wrap my head around how to remove something the package manager tells me is not present. There maybe some ghost files left behind, but still..?

Comment: Did you try to reinstall and then purge it again? What do you get from `whereis mosquitto`?

Comment: yes, I already reinstalled and purged. `whereis mosquitto` gives `mosquitto: /usr/local/sbin/mosquitto` - how to remove this?

Comment: Did you once install it manually without apt-get? Maybe you should ask your question on http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: @FabianH. yes, it was built from source once but not uninstalled. The installation directory (containing the build) was deleted. It was long time back and I just remember it now from your remark

Comment: Do you still have the source files you used to compile & install it?

Comment: no, someone removed them quite some time back. Could look through for the old versions. Would it help to download it again and try make uninstall? Thanks for being so responsive, @FabianH.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how to **uninstall a compiled application without the source** you used to install it before.

You have two options:

- Recreate the Makefile
- Manually remove the files created by make

### Recreate the Makefile

If the developer of the package has taken care of making a good uninstall rule, you can recreate the Make configuration and use the rule.

Download the source tarball of the application again and take the same version you've installed. If you passed any options to ./configure the first time you unpacked the tarball, you must give the same options again.

Then you can run `make uninstall` or `sudo make uninstall`.

### Manually remove files

It's very important to create a backup of your entire system first as you can easily remove the wrong files with this method.

Then locate the binary you can call from the console:

```
whereis name_of_your_program
```

This will locate the source/binary and manuals sections of your program. Note the directories where they are stored and gather more information about these files with `ls -l one_of_the_file` like link references and dates.

You've probably compiled the application at a single day, so you can try to locate its files based on a date in a containing directory like `/usr/local` like this:

```
find /usr/local -type f -newermt '2017-03-23'
```

Then remove the directories, binaries and configurations of the application.

### Avoid these problems in the future

Installing applications with a package management has many advantages, always try to avoid compiling by yourself.

However, sometimes have to, then you should try to use [`checkinstall`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall) instead of `make install`